# Convert array assignments to ArrayList methods

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
array[left + k] = temp[k];
```

How do I turn the left side of the statement into array list form?

My array list is called theArray... so I tried

```
theArray.get(left) + theArray.get(k) = temp[k];
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: Future reference, when something doesn't work, add the error text to the question

Answer (score 1):

For equivalent code you need to `set` (not `get`) the element at the specified index. Like,

```
theArray.set(left + k, temp[k]);
```

Comment: Of course this presumes the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has been filled with values, otherwise [`set(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-): *Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`*